# Is there any way to label Map Annotations with letters or numbers? (Android Appcelerator Titanium)

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I would like to add letters or numbers on the map Annotations, just like in this image:

[image: pins with letters]

I could not find any information on the documentation: http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Map.Annotation
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Map.View
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Google_Maps_v2_for_Android

Does anyone know if there is any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can customize the image of the annotations. So, you have to create all the pin's image from A to Z. 
Here is the property to change : http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Modules.Map.Annotation-property-image

Comment: You can even create them inside your app on-the-fly at the first start: Place an empty pin image in the images folder, create an ImageView inside a View with the image as source, put a Label on top and save the View to a file (`toImage()`).